# WinHttp TLS connection in classic asp

Tags: ssl, asp-classic, opayo, winhttp

I'm trying to send payment data to SagePay and, as they are turning off SSL, it needs to be sent using TLS.

The code I have is as follows:

```vb
set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
httpRequest.Open "POST", CStr(strPurchaseURL), false
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpRequest.send strPost
strResponse = httpRequest.responseText
```

I've been told that adding an option lets you set the protocol used but the only one I've found is:

```vb
httpRequest.option(9) = 2720
```

which allows for TLS and SSL but it can only be TLS, does anyone know what the code needs to be or is there something else I should be doing.

Comment: Also for reference there is a another poster with a [similar issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29127018/692942).

Answer (score 0):

Option `9` is [`WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx) which is

> SSL 2.0:    0x0008
>     SSL 3.0:    0x0020
>     Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0: 0x0080

So

```
httpRequest.option(9) = &H80
```

Comment: That seems to be the right code but not sure if it's the right value.  Still getting a:

    The supplied certificate has been revoked

error from SagePay.

Comment: Check out [WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066(v=vs.85).aspx) that seems to show there is more then just the three options - In fact it's more like six. Never been any good with bit flags if someone can workout what the values are.

Comment: When I'm trying to read or write .Option(9), I'm getting "Invalid procedure call or argument". Other options (8, 10, etc) work well. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows Server 2003 you may be having the same problem I was having - if you have access to the server, try the answer I added to my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140418/1081692 and see how you get on.

Comment: I need to check with the hosting company but I think you're right., Thanks!