# Using TLS 1.1 with WinHttpRequest in classic ASP

Tags: ssl, asp-classic, winhttprequest

I need to connect to another server from IIS 7.5 using TLS 1.1. I'm trying to run the code I found on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098446/winhttp-tls-connection-in-classic-asp), but I cannot write to nor read from `httpRequest.option(9)` -- the system says, invalid procedure call or argument: 'Option'. When I try Option(8) or other values, everything's OK. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the full code:

```
Const   WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols = 9
Const   SecureProtocol_TLS1_1 = 512

Set WinHttpReq = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
WinHttpReq.Open "POST", url, false
WinHttpReq.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols) = SecureProtocol_TLS1_1 'WinHttpReq.Option(9) = 512
```

Comment: You could see [if this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127018/classic-asp-iis6-win2003-server-cant-communicate-with-tls-server) is any help.

Comment: Thanks, I did see it, but the problem there was attempting to read the response immediately after sending an async request.